# GDALReprojectImage (C++) quiet

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp

I am using the `GDALReprojectImage` method from `gdalwarper.h`. Is there a way to suppress the output? The function has `GDALWarpOptions * psOptions` as an input but there in no quiet option.

I have seen that this is available in the `GDAL` sources as `bQuiet` but I cannot find a way to set this in `GDALReprojectImage`.

Is there maybe a global option I can set?

Answer (score 2):

1) A global setting to suppress warnings:
GDALAllRegister();
CPLPushErrorHandler(CPLQuietErrorHandler);

2) Disable the progress output:
In the GDALWarpOptions struct set pfnProgress to NULL.